# Is mockery during a discussion ever acceptable?

Tags: professionalism, colleagues

I had a heated technical discussion where I made my point solid and clear. And it was on a public slack channel.
But during the discussion there was a tone of mockery from someone, nothing said can be held as a direct offense just smiley faces, lols and that's about it.

Still, I am very disturbed and mad.

My question is, am I just a butthurt and overreacting? Or do I have the right to be mad and take a stand?
And if yes, what would be the appropriate action to take?

Comment: @Mari-LouA It was on a public slack channel I added this to the post.

Comment: And yes, some of the "supervisors" were there and their comment was "please cool your heels and stay civil."

Comment: Then my suggestion would be not to do anything else, let the other person make the false move first. Pretend, if need be, to rise above the occasion.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I do not know, it is part of my question.

Comment: What's "solid and clear" to one person can be rude and abrupt to another. So maybe you need to look at your own actions too. The smileys may have been an attempt to defuse the tension.

Comment: "And if yes, what would be the appropriate action to take?" What outcome are you looking for?

Comment: Sleep on it, and if you are still "butthurt" tomorrow, then it would be reasonable to need to address your concerns... in a profession manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, everything *can* be acceptable, as long as everybody is a consenting adult. I have really really great technical discussions with some people where "oh come on this is stupid" is a perfectly valid criticism, because everybody in our group knows that it will be backed up by a solid technical reason and whether it's right or not, it does transport the message clearly. Also, nobody feels challenged to keep up any looks. We all respect each other and we have nothing to prove. Maybe I was stupid. Happens to the best of us and pretty regularly. No point denying it. I'm happy to have someone point out a technical flaw, so after the discussion, the product is better.

But that does not work in every group. Wether it's just perceived or real, if someone at the table feels they need to keep up a good "look" (for example they don't want their boss to know they made a mistake), this will end badly. Insultingly direct language only works if clear communication is a priority for all. If there are other priorities involved, it becomes a liability best avoided.

To me, mockery is another level of insult though. "Mocking" is about people, not technical concepts. I can call a backup concept "stupid", that just means it's bad and won't work. But I would not call the person stupid. That's a personal insult and does not transport any clear message to solve problems. It should never be about someone on a personal level.

So first, think about whether the uninvited rude criticism was targeted at your work or you personally. By my understanding of English, I would say "mockery" is something that targeted you personally.

Whether you are right to feel mad is something only you can decide.

But you would be right about wanting it to stop, because it is not constructive. You cannot take any action to improve whatever you were talking about, when someone mocks you personally.

So your best course of action is to stay calm and professional and focus not on "this makes me mad" but on "this hinders me in doing my work". For the first, you will get some token help from your bosses and maybe HR, because they *have* to help you, for the latter however, you will get help from your bosses, because they *want* you to work better.

So say something like:

> I feel a little distracted by the smileys and lols. Maybe we can focus on the task at hand instead. I presented a plan to frabnudle the Crumchicks, are there any ideas for improvements?

This makes it clear you are not interested in getting into a mudslinging contest, you are a professional who is here to do their job. Your bosses will prefer this and they will note that you were constructive while someone else was just misbehaving.

---

Just in case you ever get into that situation without any bosses in the room and the person won't stop: You don't get them to stop by complaining or getting mad. If they do not get your "lets stay professional" signal, and have to somehow shut them up, stop plaing their game. If you ever watched 8 Mile you know what I'm about to say. Although I don't advise to take professional behavior lessons from a rap movie. If someone is mocking you, instead of getting mad about it, showing it has hurt you, do the opposite. Join in.

Say something like:

> Was that supposed to be me you were immitating? Oh come on, I don't sound like that. I sound way nerdier. And when have you ever heard me complain without making it about the budget? Come on, try again, nerdier and mention our tight budget at least once. Show some effort here, you will get good at it.

That's not the preferred way, but it's still more powerful than getting mad.

Answer (score 4):

> Is mockery during a discussion ever acceptable?

I would say generally that with all forms of behaviour, there are degrees of acceptability.

For example, mocking a coworker for having cancer, vs mocking a coworker in a light-handed manner knowing it will be taken it good spirits, are two different forms of mockery which I would say are on opposite ends of the scale.

> And yes, some of the "supervisors" were there and their comment was
> "please cool your heels and stay civil."

I think that's an entirely appropriate response from the supervisor.

> Or do I have the right to be mad and take a stand?

Being mad can be justifiable, but that shouldn't dictate any behavior. In fact, severe negative emotions are never a good starting point from determining what you next steps should be.

You should consider what outcome you actually want, and decide what course of action would best deliver it.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite simple:

When having a solid technical point on a topic during a discussion, some smiley faces or lols shouldn't make you mad and disturbed at all.

You can't change other peoples behaviour, opinion or reaction, but you yourself can keep it at a professional level and remain calm - let other folks make a fool out of themselves..

> *"Is mockery during a discussion ever acceptable?"*

That depends on work-culture, the type of mockery and how it is meant and perceived. I'd say it's definitely unprofessional, if it is to some degree acceptable depends on opinions of those involved..